# Bayes' Theorem - is the probability quantifiable in this case?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability

Question 4.49 in Newbold (8. ed)

> A company receives large shipments of parts from two sources. Seventy percent of the shipments come from a supplier whose shipments typically contain $10\%$ defectives, while the remainder are from a supplier whose shipments typically contain $20\%$ defectives. A manager receives a shipment but does not know the source. A random sample of $20$ items from this shipment is tested, and $1$ of the parts is found to be defective. What is the probability that this shipment came from the more reliable supplier? (Hint: Use Bayes' theorem.)

Using $P(A)=0.7$, $P(B)=0.3$, $P(D|A)=0.1$ and $P(D|B)=0.2$ I have made a two-way table and came to the conclusion that $P(A|D)=0.538$ and $P(B|D)=0.461$. So OK, a little over half of the defective parts come from supplier A (which makes sense, given they provide $70\%$ of the parts, even if their defect-rate is lower). However, I don't understand how all this relates to the actual question ("What is the probability that this shipment came from the more reliable supplier?"). From what could I calculate that? Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more reliable supplier is $A$ because its defection rate is smaller. And, we need the following probability:
$$P(A|1D, 19D')=\frac{P(1D,19D'|A)P(A)}{P(1D,19D'|A)P(A)+P(1D,19D'|B)P(B)}$$

And, for example, one of the terms can be calculated as $$P(1D,19D'|A)={20 \choose 1}0.1^10.9^{19}$$

The rest can be calculated similarly and then substituted.

Comment: Thank you, @gunes. I've done it and now know that the probability that the shipment came from supplier A is 0.916225 :) (I always understand it (eventually), when you explain it but by myself I could never come up with these solutions... :| )